# why this pseudo class selector is not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use :after selector to draw a inside-border in every div I hover. Now the ":after" pseudo class doesn't work? any idea why this selector doesn't work? if I just use the :hover pseudo class works, the thing is that I want to use both classes!

Have a look at this [EX](http://jsbin.com/akidax/edit#html,live)

thanks!

```html
<body>
    <h1>Example Six</h1>
                
    <p>Grade: A</p>
    <p>this is the thing</p>

    <div class="w3c">
        <div id="tab16">
            <a href="#tab16">cars</a>
            
            <div class="test">
                <div><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/176x106/" /></div>
            </div>                    
        </div> <!-- ends tab16 -->        
        <div id="tab17">
            <a href="#tab17">othercars</a>
        <div>
            <div><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/180x110/" /></div>
            <div><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/180x110/" /></div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- ends .w3c -->
</body>
```

The css:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
    
.w3c {
    min-height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    width: 554px;
}
.w3c > div {
    display: inline;
}
.w3c > div > a {
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #666666;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.w3c > div:not(:target) > a {
    border-bottom: 0;
    background: #b0b0b0;
    /*-moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #eee); */
}   
.w3c > div:target > a {
    background: white;
    color: #b0b0b0;
}
                
.w3c > div > div {
    background: white;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 596px;
    height: 133px;
}   
.w3c  div  div > div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height:110px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.w3c  div div > div:hover:after {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:178px;
    height: 108px;
}
            
/* .w3c > div > div > a  > img:after {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width:178;
    height: 108px;
} */
.w3c > div:not(:target) > div {
    position: absolute;
}
.w3c > div:target > div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: `:after` is a pseudo-element, `:hover` is a pseudo-class. You *can* use both together.

Comment: On hover do you want to display both the red border and the black one? If so, you can achieve it without the :after thing, but with different css/html combo

Comment: @boltClock hey! wondering how can u edit the code in the right way with colors and so ? I saw u did it in my post. :) thanks!

Comment: I was testing the code in your JS Bin and it seems to save over yours instead of forking it. Whoops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `:after` pseudo-element to show up you need to give it content and display it as a block.

Then, absolutely position the `:after` and relatively position the `div` itself:

```
.w3c div div > div {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.w3c div div > div:hover:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 178px;
    height: 108px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what the problem is.

`::after` is used to add content after an existing element, not to style elements that come after things.

You might want to use `nth-child()` to target the x elements, or every x element.

```
.w3c div div > div:nth-child(2):hover {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: yes and no, look at this ex: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-multiple-borders-with-simple-css/ but thanks for yr input anyway! :)